# ToolstripButton remain focused in an MDI Form

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, toolstrip

I have a MDI Form that is MDI Container, a ToolStrip Bar with some buttons and a child form.
On child form there is a third's part component for draw like CAD application.

If I click on a ToolStripButton to start draw something, button remains in a state like pressed and to execute the operation I must click somewhere on the screen.

If I use MenuStrip I don't have any trouble.

Why the toolstrip have this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vector Draw Framework have a problem with ToolStrip and for execute a command is necessary to use PostCommandExute("") method.

Answer (score 0):

If the focus stays in the button, you can focus the CAD part manually to use it:

```
public void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Other code...
   cadComponent.Focus();
}
```

Not sure why it behaves like that, though.